# How to assign values of array to another array(making copy) in c?

Tags: c, arrays, char, multidimensional-array

I want to copy 2d array and assign it to another.

**In python i will do something like this**

```
grid = [['a','b','c'],['d','e','f'],['g','h','i']]
grid_copy = grid
```

**I want to do same in C.**

```
char grid[3][3] = {{'a','b','c'},{'d','e','f'},{'g','h','i'}};
```

How do i copy this array to copy_grid ?

Comment: Note that your Python code does not copy the data. Both `grid` and `grid_copy` refer to the same list. Try changing an element in one and see what happens to the other.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [memcpy](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memcpy) , don't forget to include `<string.h>`

```
#include <string.h>
void *memcpy(void *dest, const void *src, size_t n);
```

Or, do it manually using loop put each value one by one.

Answer (score 12):

Use `memcpy` standard function:

```
char grid[3][3] = {{'a','b','c'},{'d','e','f'},{'g','h','i'}};
char grid_copy[3][3];

memcpy(grid_copy, grid, sizeof grid_copy);
```

Comment: how can i assign particular value like grid_copy[0][1] = grid[2][2]. I know this is wrong but i think you know what i mean to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Although the answers are correct, one should remark that if the array is inside a structure, assigning structures will copy the array as well:

```
struct ArrStruct
{
    int arr[5][3];
};

int main(int argc, char argv[])
{
    struct ArrStruct as1 = 
    { { { 65, 77, 8 }, 
    { 23, -70, 764 }, 
    { 675, 517, 97 }, 
    { 9, 233, -244 }, 
    { 66, -32, 756 } } };

    struct ArrStruct as2 = as1;//as2.arr is initialized to the content of as1.arr

    return 0;
}
```