# is there a way to use the ternary operator with arrays?

Tags: c++, conditional-operator

I was trying to write an algorithm that would take 2 numbers as input and output them in ascending order using the ternary operator, but on line 20:24 it tells me:

> error: invalid array assignment

Can someone help me?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
     int a, b;
     int c[2];
     int d[2];
     int e[2];
     cout << "inserire il primo numero: ";
     cin >> a;
     cout << "inserire il secondo numero: ";
     cin >> b;

     c[0] = b;
     c[1] = a;
     d[0] = a;
     d[1] = b;
     e = (a > b) ? c : d;
     cout << e;
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with ternary operator, C-style arrays are not assignable. `e = c;` would fail just the same. You can use `std::array<int, 2> c;` (same for `d` and `e`) and it would work.

Comment: You cannot assign an array to something else. Perhaps you want `e` to be a pointer instead? Though even then the line `cout << e;` won't do what you probably expect it to

Answer (score 1):

as long as the left side has the appropriate `=` operator, you can write this statement. C-Style arrays do not have this as you try to change their pointer. [read more](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array).

you can use `std::array<int, 2>`, which has the `operator=` and offers many benefits ([read more](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

int main() {
    int a, b;
    std::array<int, 2> c;
    std::array<int, 2> d;
    std::array<int, 2> e;

    std::cout << "inserire il primo numero: ";
    std::cin >> a;
    std::cout << "inserire il secondo numero: ";
    std::cin >> b;

    c = { b, a };
    d = { a, b };

    e = (a > b) ? c : d;

    for (auto& i : e) {
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    }
}
```

---

read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) why you shouldn't `use namespace std;`.

Comment: thank you very much for your fix, I'll start not using anymore using namespace std;

Answer (score -1):

Ternay operator works fine. In your code, the problem was in assigning the array.
You can't assign an array like that.

One of the ways you can follow:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
     int a, b;
     int c[2];
     int d[2];
     int e[2];
     cout << "inserire il primo numero: ";
     cin >> a;
     cout << "inserire il secondo numero: ";
     cin >> b;

     c[0] = b;
     c[1] = a;
     d[0] = a;
     d[1] = b;
     (a > b) ? memcpy(e, c, sizeof c) : memcpy(e, d, sizeof d);

     cout << e[0] << " " << e[1] << endl;
}
```

Please check the below URL to learn more ways for assigning one array to another other than running a loop.

[How to assign values of array to another array(making copy)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13903388/how-to-assign-values-of-array-to-another-arraymaking-copy-in-c)